# Ruby - How do I change a single line break to a double line break?

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have this in a file called "tao":

```
If you can talk about it, it ain't Tao. If it has a name, it's just another thing.  
Tao doesn't have a name. Names are for ordinary things.
```

And I want to open it up in ruby, and change it to:

```
If you can talk about it, it ain't Tao. If it has a name, it's just another thing.
  
Tao doesn't have a name. Names are for ordinary things.
```

I know how to read the file, and get the contents into a string (let's call it `tao_string`), but I'm not sure how to change the single line break into a double line break. I'd suspect something via regex, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
tao_string2 = tao_string.gsub("\n", "\n\n")
```

or in-place with [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21):

```
tao_string.gsub!("\n", "\n\n")
```

This will replace *all* line breaks in your string by double line breaks.

Comment: I swear I tried that before, but either way, that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: What if you run this multiple times? The number of `\n` characters is going to increase exponentially!

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: Yes, is there anything surprising?

Comment: Shouldn't that be accounted for? I'd put a [`squeeze "\n"`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) before calling `gsub`.

Comment: I think this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira what does squeeze do?

Comment: @ChintanParikh: It replaces sequences of the same character by just one instance of the character. `"aaaabbbcccd".squeeze` is `"abcd". See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze.